# Basic canvas collision not working in for loops

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I'm encountering a collision issue that I can't quite figure out. The point of my program is to generate a random number of circles (between 2 and 15) with random velocities in a bounding box that is 1920x900. If they touch each other, they're supposed to fly off in opposite directions (not great physics, I know, but that'll come later.)

To do this, I've got four arrays: two for the coordinates of the circles (xcords[] and ycords[], and two for the momentum of each circle (xdirs[] and ydirs[]).

Here's my collision function

```
function collides(x, y)
    {
        if(Math.hypot(xcords[y]-xcords[x], ycords[y]-ycords[x]) < 50)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

When I hardcode certain values, such as

```
if(collides(xcords[1],xcords[0])
{
     xdirs[0] *= -1;
     xdirs[1] *= -1;
     ydirs[0] *= -1;
     ydirs[1] *= -1;
}
```

then it works fine. The two circles I hardcode will collide correctly. But when I try to apply this to every circle:

```
for(i=0; i<circles; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<circles; j++)
            {
                if(collides(xcords[i], xcords[j]))
                {
                    xdirs[i] *= -1;
                    xdirs[j] *= -1;
                    ydirs[i] *= -1;
                    ydirs[j] *= -1;
                }   
            }
        }
```

Then the circles just ignore each other, and I have no idea why. This is the only time I use a double for loop in this code, but I do the first for loop multiple times, and it handles it correctly for every other function.

Here's a jsfiddle for it. https://jsfiddle.net/sekbr0pg/ 
The bounding box is a little off, but it's enough to see that the collision is wonky.

Comment: Hint: if x collides with y, y also collides with x. If you put a breakpoint inside the if branch, you will see they aren't completely ignoring each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take circle 1 and circle 2. You want to check whether they collide or not *only once*. Is the following loop good for that?

```
for(i=0; i<circles; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<circles; j++){
        // if collides ...
        }
}
```

Answer is no, and the reason is that they will run twice, for `i=1 and j=2` and `i=2 and j=1`. So basically it won't change anything since -1*-1 = 1. In your loop change `j=0` to `j=i+1`.

Also your `collides` function accept circles, so I think `collides(i,j)` will do the job.

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that. That solved the problem completely.